# VB.NET Parameter has no default Value

Tags: vb.net

Am create this code to insert the items to the table name as emp_state, the problem is in @d3, when I select the item from the combobox it give me error that Parameter @d3 has no default value?

Here is the code, please give me a solution

```
Dim sSQL As String = "insert into emp_state(Badge,Name,State,Date_of_Join,Date_of_Termination,Reasons,Information) values (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7)"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, cn)


        ' Badge
        Dim Badge As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d1", OleDbType.VarWChar, 8)
        Badge.Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Badge)

        ' Name
        Dim Name As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d2", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        Name.Value = TextBox2.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Name)

        ' State
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Dim State As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d3", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20)
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf("State")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(State)


        'Date_of_Join
        Dim Date_of_Join As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d4", OleDbType.Date, 15)
        Date_of_Join.Value = dtpDOB.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Date_of_Join)

        'Date_of_Termination
        Dim Date_of_Termination As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d5", OleDbType.Date, 15)
        Date_of_Termination.Value = DateTimePicker1.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Date_of_Termination)

        'Reasons
        Dim Reasons As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d6", OleDbType.VarWChar, 9999)
        Reasons.Value = TextBox3.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Reasons)

        'Information
        Dim Information As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d7", OleDbType.VarWChar, 9999)
        Information.Value = TextBox4.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Information)
```

Comment: Is anything selected in `ComboBox1`?  Also, you can shorten your code by using `AddWithValue` - `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf("State")`

Comment: there is no selected item, when i try to select its give me directly the first item from the items, and its not updated in the DB

Comment: `@d3` doesn't follow the pattern of all of the other parameters - all of the others you have `Dim <parametername> as OldDbParameter` on one line, and then on the next line you set that parameter's value. But you don't set any value for the `State` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ' State
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    Dim State As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d3", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20)
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf("State")
    cmd.Parameters.Add(State)
```

Read this part again.

1. You set the combobox to select the first item
2. then you create your parameter
3. you then set the index of your combobox to an index by trying to find some item?
4. then you add your empty parameter to the parameterList

Im asuming what you wanted to do is:

```
   ' State
    ' ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    Dim State As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@d3", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20)
    State.Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add(State)
```

Comment: I have four items in the combobox its as Resignation, Release, Transfer and Termination, when I try to select the second or third it ca not be its only automatically select the first one for me?? what is the solution??

Comment: Doesnt matter how many items you have in that Combobox, if you're options are set with the right value the above will normally add the correct value to your parameter. The issue you had was that you are setting the combobox to the first item yourself by doing ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

Comment: the type in the access DB of the state is text, have i need to change it?

Comment: shouldnt be necesarry. However, make sure your Combobox has the right value op its option tag (or listItems). In oder to check that out you should post the code of your webpage /code behind aswell